# how can we equalize the fonts of mathtt and texttt

Tags: fonts, math-mode, typewriter

I'm trying to use a mono-font in my text, but it seems that mono texts differ in character map in math and text environment. Is there any solution?

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
\begin{document}

\texttt{Farschad \% + - * \$  ! }

\[
\mathtt{Farschad \% + - * \$ !}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: what is the purpose of your question?  do you want to make the output look like a manuscript that  was typed on a typewriter, or something else?

Comment: I want to type computer codes with ttfamily fonts. However, some parts of the code should be clarified with mathematical formula and I want to use the same font in mathematical mode. so I use \mathtt instead of \texttt because I have to use mathematical operations. However, the fonts in two environment differ with each other.

Answer (score 8):

`\mathtt` only changes the math alphabets. Just use `\texttt` in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\texttt{foo-bar!}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it is not a good solution because you can not use mathematical operations in text mode. for example the following text produces error:    $\texttt{1^2}$

Comment: @Farschad: In fact, mathematical operators are not available in typewriter fonts.

Comment: the solution can be to use `\texttt{}` always but with the maths operators, right? so, no problems :)

Answer (score 5):

this may or may not do all that you want.  it requires `amsmath` to get the sub- and superscripts in the correct size, and you will have to handle all the spacing yourself.

there is probably a package for this, but i don't know it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Here is some computer code.

\texttt{%
a + b + c = 123$^{\texttt{2}}$ - x$_{\texttt{3}}$
}

That is all.
\end{document}
```

[image: output from sample code]

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. The way you use works fine but it requires typing a lot of \texttt. I want to see if a shorter method is available. If we just make both commands (i.e mathtt and texttt) using the same character map, then it would be a good solution. Unfortunately, mathtt uses a few character map.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `fontspec` you should also be using either `mathspec` or `unicode-math`. If you use `mathspec`, then you can set the font for `\mathtt` like this:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
\setmathtt{Courier New}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Farschad \% + - * \$  ! }

\[
\mathtt{Farschad \% + - * \$ !}
\]

\end{document}
```

Similarly, if you use `unicode-math`, then:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\mathtt->\mathup]{Courier New}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Farschad \% + - * \$  ! }

\[
\mathtt{Farschad \% + - * \$ !}
\]

\end{document}
```

Admittedly the results are not perfect – there is no way to change the font of non-alphabetic symbols – but it is a start.