# The typewriter font for digits in the \mathtt command with the mathspec package

Tags: fonts, mathspec

First an MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}%after amsmath
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin){Times}%

\title{An Example}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

In equations, the setting acts as $f(x)=x^2+2021$ and $\mathtt{2021abcdef}$, while in the texts the setting acts as \texttt{2021abcdefg}.
    
\end{document}
```

Compiled with `XeLaTex`, the output is as follows

[image]

Question: As you see, the digits in `\mathtt`and `\texttt` commands have different appearances: the former are in the `Times` series font and the latter are indeed in the default typewriter font (`Computer Modern`). Is there one way to

1. make the digits in `\mathtt`and `\texttt` commands both have the
   same appearance with the default typewriter font, and
2. still make the digits in `\mathrm`, `\mathit` and so on have appearances with the `Times` series font?

Note that the similar question will also come out when we replace the `Times` series font with other fonts or when we use `\mathit`, `\mathbf`, `\mathsf` and so on.

Comment: Is `unicode-math` package instead of `mathspec` an option?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127574/how-can-we-equalize-the-fonts-of-mathtt-and-texttt `\mathtt` changes the letters but not digits, operators, or spacing. `\texttt` works on all glyphs (if they are in the font). Possibility: With `unicode-math` package, mapping tt to everything else might be a solution. Do you want *all* math to be tt, or just some?

Comment: @Cicada What I want is: when we use `\mathtt` over digits under the mathspec package the output of digits should be tt font.

Comment: Try the \setallmonofonts command (`texdoc mathspec` 4.5), e.g., `\setallmonofonts[Colour=red]{CMU Typewriter Text}`. Doc: "This command is equivalent to: `\setmonofont[⟨font features⟩]{⟨font name⟩}
\setmathtt[⟨font features⟩]{⟨font name⟩}` ".

Comment: Works for me. Use whatever tt font you have on your system. I cannot guess your set-up - there are too many variables. The CMU fonts I used as a test are part of TeXLive. Ask a separate question about fonts. Have you got the font installed? Have you typed the name correctly? Have you tried the filename method (see fontspec manual)? What was the exact error message? Do other fonts give the same error? The bit about `Colour=red` will error out if you don't have a `usepackage{xcolor}` line. You can delete that option (if you have used it) and don't want colour to confirm mathtt works as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find one way to this question by myself. We can solve the problem in the following ways:

1. Delete the `Digits` option in `\setallmainfonts` command.
2. Set the digits in the math environment to be `YOURFONT`(mine is Times) by the following codes. The crucial point is that you should know the `ENCODING` and `ABBREVIATION` for `YOURFONT` which the digits are in, for example, them for computer modern regular font are `OT1` and `cmr` respectively.

After the setting, commands such as `\mathit`, `\mathbf`, `\mathsf` and `\mathtt` over digits recover to be normal again.

```
\setallmainfonts(Latin){YOURFONT}%
\makeatletter
\DeclareSymbolFont{digtsfont}{ENCODING}{ABBREVIATION}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{digtsfont}{`9}
\makeatother
```

Now I give one possible way to find the `ENCODING` and `ABBREVIATION` for `YOURFONT`:

1. Put `\setallmainfonts(Latin){YOURFONT}%` in the preamble and compile the `.tex` file.
2. Open the `.aux` file produced after the compiling, and you may find the `ENCODING` and `ABBREVIATION` for `YOURFONT`.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood the requirements correctly, then `mathspec`'s `\setallmonofonts` command in one step usefully sets both mathtt and texttt modes to use the same font.

[image: CMU TT]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setallmonofonts[Colour=red]{CMU Typewriter Text}
\newcommand\sample{\parbox{0.8\textwidth}{
plain: text 123 

\textbackslash texttt: \texttt{text 123}

plain: $123 x^2+456 y^2=789 z^2$

\textbackslash mathtt: $\mathtt{123 x^2+456 y^2=789 z^2}$

$x$ term only: $\mathtt{123 x^2}+456 y^2=789 z^2$
}}

\begin{document}

CMU Typewriter Text

\fbox{\sample}
\end{document}
```

Any typewriter font can slot in there.

Latin Modern Mono:

[image: LMM]

Inconsolatazi4:

[image: Inconsolata]

Even non-tt fonts.

Punk Nova:

[image: Punk Nova]

Just a matter of finding an appropriate font suitable for the purpose.

Comment: I use MacTex. Is CMU Typewriter Text contained in MacTex? It seems not to be so. Even if there is CMU Typewriter Text in MacTex, when we use `\mathbf` over digits the problem still exists. So I think there are problems in the codes of the `mathspec` package.

Comment: Ask a separate question. In math mode, the formatting commands do not nest. My understand is they are intended to apply to individual symbols or operators, not to a string of characters like text-mode format commands do. So it may be an XY question. `mathspec` recommends to use `unicode-math` if you are using Unicode maths fonts (there are many more around now than the two when `mathspec` was written).

Comment: By the way what's your real name? I'd like to show thanks to people who help me a lot on latex when writing my book. Also, how do you read your surname?