# Writing Mathematica code in latex

Tags: macros, code

I am trying to type the following Mathematica code

```
e[a_, -1] := (1 - 2^(-a)) Zeta[a]
```

in Latex file using \texttt{....} but the file didnt compile. But when I ignored the signs ( ^ , _ ), the file compiled nicely. Here is what I typed:

```
\texttt{e[a, -1] := (1 - 2(-a)) Zeta[a]}
```

and here is what I got

[image]

Any idea how to fix the issue of the signs ( ^ , _ ) ?

Thank you,

Here is the commands I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=webgreen,
filecolor=webbrown,
citecolor=webgreen]{hyperref}
\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphics,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{secdot}
\sectionfont{\centering}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.9in}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}
```

Comment: A side note: the presented code has multiples of some packages in use (these should be removed). Another reduction can be to use `\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}` which would reduce the header by three lines.     Otherwise the given code is all front matter and is missing the main body of code to help produce the desired output.

Comment: Whatever else you decide to do, *please* stop loading the `epsf` and `latexsym` packages.  Next, there's no need to load the `graphics` package since you also load the `graphicx` package. No need to load `amsfonts` twice; in fact, there's no need to load this package *at all* since it's loaded automatically by `amssymb`.  And, don't load the `fullpage` package and do get rid of  the five `\setlength` directives. Instead, depending on the paper size in use, execute either `\usepackage[margin=1in, letterpaper]{geometry}` or `\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}`.

Comment: `Writing Mathematica code in latex` 

This question showed up under "Related" for something comicbook-related. Admittedly, it's a lot less sexy than expected.

Comment: Have you tried `\verb/e[a, -1] := (1 - 2(-a)) Zeta[a]/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option given the presented code and expected result:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{article}

%----- packages ------------
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=webgreen,
filecolor=webbrown,
citecolor=webgreen]{hyperref}
\usepackage{secdot}
   \sectionfont{\centering}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
   \definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
   \definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%------- defined conditions -----------
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.1in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.9in}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}


\begin{document}

Sample $1$: This Mathematica code, \texttt{$e[a, -1] := (1 - 2^{-a}) \, Zeta[a]$}, can be written as \[ \text{e[a, -1]:=} \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^a}\right) \, \zeta(a) \].

Sample $2$: Other \texttt{\&} elements \texttt{\%}. 


\end{document}
```

gives the result:

[image]

There are other questions with results that may help. For example [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127574/how-can-we-equalize-the-fonts-of-mathtt-and-texttt) gives some examples. Also note that `\texttt{...}` is for text and still requires the usual math mode components if math related material is added.

Comment: The backslash is all I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like a job for the [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package and its `lstlisting` environment.

[image]

```
%%% I've tried to streamline and simplify the preamble
\documentclass[12pt%,reqno % 'reqno' is the default
              ]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amscd}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays

\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}

\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
   \definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
   \definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=webgreen,
     filecolor=webbrown,
     citecolor=webgreen]{hyperref}
     
%%%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{graphics,amsmath,amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%%%%\usepackage{latexsym}
%%%%%\usepackage{epsf}
%%%\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{secdot}

%%%\usepackage{fullpage}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.1in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{.1in}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{8.9in}

%\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

% new code
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings} % for 'lstlisting' environment and '\lstinline' macro


\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Mathematica, morekeywords={DirichletBeta}}
\begin{lstlisting}
e[a_, -1] := (1 - 2^(-a)) Zeta[a]
e[a_, 1]  := DirichletBeta[a]
f[q_, p_] := Sum[e[2k,1]e[2k+1,-1],{k,0,Floor[p/2]}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment and revised posting. While the `\lstlisting` *environment* is fine for typesetting entire code chunks -- as was shown in the original form of the query, which unfortunately is no longer shown in the OP's query -- in a nicely formatted way, the `\lstinline` *macro* is well-suited for typesetting code fragments within running text. E.g., using the same preamble as before, the instructions

```
\lstset{language=Mathematica, morekeywords={DirichletBeta}}

\lipsum[1][1] \lstinline{e[a_, -1] := (1 - 2^(-a)) Zeta[a]}. \lipsum[1][2]
```

generate the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rico. Please check my question again I've just edited it.

Comment: @AliShadhar - Please see the addendum I posted.

Comment: Thank you again Mico